# Duplicate Primary Keys?

Tags: sql

Looking at an example from [Java Persistence with Hibernate](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/), there are 2 tables:

```
create table USERS (
    USER_ID bigint not null primary key,
    USERNAME varchar(15) not null unique,
    NAME varchar(50) not null,
    ...
)
create table BILLING_DETAILS (
    BILLING_DETAILS_ID bigint not null primary key,
    ACCOUNT_NUMBER VARCHAR(10) not null unique,
    ACCOUNT_NAME VARCHAR(50) not null,
    ACCOUNT_TYPE VARCHAR(2) not null,
    USER_ID bigint foreign key references USERS
)
```

The book mentions that the following indicates a `many-to-one` relationship:

`USER_ID bigint foreign key references USERS`

Next, it says that the following SQL statements show `one-to-one` associations:

```
USER_ID bigint unique foreign key references USERS
BILLING_DETAILS_ID bigint primary key foreign key references USERS
```

As I understand, the first statement means that `USER_ID` of the `BILLING_DETAILS` table will be unique and reference the primary_key of the `USERS` table, i.e. `references USERS`.

The second makes the `BILLING_DETAILS_ID` the primary_key and reference the `USERS`'s primary key.

If we used both of these `one-to-one` relationships, then we'd have duplicate fields: `USER_ID` and `BILLING_DETAILS_ID` since they effectively are the same data?

Comment: There is a difference between a `primary key` (which is `billiing_details_id`) and a unique column.  Only one column (or set of columns) can be the primary key.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, so, executing both of the SQL 1-to-1 statements would result in duplicate fields, however the difference is that only `BILLING_DETAILS_ID` would be the primary key?

Comment: The fields might not be duplicates.  Nothing in the above code specifies how the values are filled in.  If you make the primary keys auto-incrementing, then they would be quite similar (race conditions, for instance, could cause differences in the values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't necessarily the same data in the absence of an additional CHECK() constraint that requires user ID and billing details ID to be equal.

I have not read the book, but as a database professional, I'd consider that implementation of a one-to-one relationship to be in error. A unique constraint on billing_details.user_id, along with its obvious foreign key constraint, is sufficient to guarantee a one-to-one relationship between the two tables. (That kind of relationship doesn't make much sense in the real world, though, when you think about what *billing details* means.)

From a database viewpoint, letting billing_details.user_id be nullable seems questionable, too.

---

**Later . . .**

I just thought of an alternative explanation of what the book says. When it says

```
USER_ID bigint unique foreign key references USERS
BILLING_DETAILS_ID bigint primary key foreign key references USERS
```

it's describing two *different* ways to implement a one-to-one relationship. It's not saying you should use *both* statements to implement *one* one-to-one relationship.

But this, too, is an error, in that USER_ID isn't declared to be NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

BILLING_DETAILS_ID is practically the primary key, which means it cannot be duplicated. However, USER_ID is NOT, you can have duplicated USER_ID in the table BILLING_DETAILS, it is treated as a data which should have a reference in the table USER.

the relationship between BILLING_DETAILS and USER is one(USER)-to-many(BILLING_DETAILS)